# Getting detailed version information of the executed program

Tags: windbg

I'm trying to get the version information of the executable from a crash dump. It's not that simple, so please read the whole question before you come up with an answer that does not work.

#### lm vm appname

Basically I can do `lmv` to get the version details, and that is exactly the information I want.

If you don't know how to get the version information of the executable, you can google a bit and get [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a3f73d8b-1d0b-49d6-951e-edcdf485bebc/windbg-how-to-get-version-info-for-the-exe-from-which-a-dump-file-was-generated?forum=windbg), which suggests

> `lm vm appname` (without .exe)

This works probably in 90% of the cases. However, it has the following two issues which I want to resolve in an automated analysis:

1. What is `appname` if I don't know the executable in advance?
2. In special cases like Notepad++, the module name is not `notepad++` but rather `notepad__`

Now I *can* find out the executable name using `|`, but extracting the name of the executable from that output is not trivial.

#### Finding the exe in the list of modules

It is possible to find executables in the list of modules with a command like

```
.shell -ci "lmf" findstr "\.exe"
```

We can then extract the address and list the details with

```
.foreach /ps 9999 (exe {.shell -ci "lmf" findstr "\.exe"}) {lmva exe}
```

Still, there is a problem: .NET processes can load assemblies that are not DLLs but EXEs. In that case, the output might be wrong if the first result is not the main executable but a EXE loaded later.

#### List of modules

It is possible to get a list of modules using `lm1m`. And usually, the first one in that list is the executable.

It is then possible to extract the first line and get the details for it. A command looks like

```
.foreach /ps 9999 (exe {lm1m}) { lm vm ${exe}}
```

Unfortunately, it is not guaranteed that the executable is the first module. The modules are sorted by address. And IMHO it might happen that the executable is loaded at a higher address.

#### Question

How do I get `lmv` information for the main executable reliably.

Assumptions that can be made:

- user mode crash dump of type `/ma`
- only one process is being debugged

Comment: `lmv a $exentry` should be fairly reliable, assuming `$exentry` is, which I haven't tested under your circumstances.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: wow, that seems simple. I didn't think `lm` would handle addresses other than the start address. Looks like the best option so far. Would you like to convert that into an answer?

Comment: Well, you could self-answer if you could verify that it won't fail with a .NET process loading multiple executable assemblies (possibly relocated). I don't *think* that affects `$exentry`, but I'm certainly too lazy to try. :-)

Comment: I think @JeroenMostert is the easiest and best answer. There are possible other ways to do it (e.g. the first entry in `_PEB.Ldr.InLoadOrderModuleList` which always describe the main executable), but I can't think of any that would simpler than `$exentry`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert), a suitable command might be

```
lmv a $exentry
```

This works, because `lm` is smart enough to accept address which are within a module. `$exentry` gives the entry point of the first executable.

You find the description in the pseudo register syntax:

> $exentry: The address of the entry point of the first executable of the current process.

[Source: WinDbg help]

For the C# part, we can use the following piece of code for testing:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace exentry
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var fullExe = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
            var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullExe);
            var newexe = Path.Combine(path, "exentry2.exe");
            File.Copy(fullExe, newexe);

            Assembly.LoadFrom(newexe);
            Console.WriteLine("Debug now");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```